# Error in merging GO terms - Merge function

Tags: r, merge

I have two data frames

```
    A ### data frame contain GO ids

    GOBPID

    G0:00987
    GO:06723
    GO:02671
    GO:00654
    GO:00132

   B ### containing GO ids with their associated columns

    GOBPID    term

    GO:08765  flavonoid synthesis
    G0:00133  biosynthesis process
    G0:00987  carotenoid synthesis
    GO:06723  coumarin synthesis
    GO:00824  metabolic process
    GO:02671  leaf morphology
    GO:00654  response to light
    GO:00268  response to stress
    GO:00135  pathogen defense
    GO:00132  spindle formation
```

I wanted to extract only the common ids from both A and B and delete the rest of the rows

```
    #from A    # from B    # from B
    G0:00987   G0:00987    carotenoid synthesis
    GO:06723   GO:06723    coumarin synthesis
    GO:02671   GO:02671    leaf morphology
    GO:00654   GO:00654    response to light
    GO:00132   GO:00132    spindle formation
```

and did the following:

```
  list of terms<- merge(A,B,by.x="GOBPID",by.y="GOBPID")
```

But there was an error and returned a dataframe of 0 length which had only the column names but no merging.

```
  [1] GOBPID        Term     
   <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

and again tried the following

```
  merge(A,B,by.x="row.names",by.y="row.names")
```

which just merges the two data frame but does not give me the common ids. The  5 ids from A are just matched to the first 5 ids in B and does not consider the merging of only common ids.

I have added the two datasets as well:

```
  [dataset A][http://public.justcloud.com/dldzm0fnsp.4540049] 
  [dataset B][http://public.justcloud.com/dldzmx1758.4540049]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use standard dataframe subsetting:

```
R> dd_B[dd_B$GOBPID %in% dd_A$GOBPID,]
     GOBPID                label
3  G0:00987 carotenoid synthesis
4  GO:06723   coumarin synthesis
6  GO:02671      leaf morphology
7  GO:00654    response to light
10 GO:00132    spindle formation
```

The `%in%` operator tests whether an `GOBPID` from `B` is in `A`

I presume you don't need the first column since its just a duplicate of the middle column

---

Code for above example:

```
dd_A = data.frame(GOBPID = c("G0:00987", "GO:06723", "GO:02671", "GO:00654", "GO:00132"))

dd_B = read.table(textConnection('GO:08765  "flavonoid synthesis"
G0:00133  "biosynthesis process"
G0:00987  "carotenoid synthesis"
GO:06723  "coumarin synthesis"
GO:00824  "metabolic process"
GO:02671  "leaf morphology"
GO:00654  "response to light"
GO:00268  "response to stress"
GO:00135  "pathogen defense"
GO:00132  "spindle formation"'))

colnames(dd_B) = c("GOBPID", "label")

dd_B[dd_B$GOBPID %in% dd_A$GOBPID,]
```

Comment: @ csgillespie : It still returns <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names). I have my own data in the very same format except that they are more columns in B than I wrote here but guess that will not make any difference.

Comment: @ csgillespie : B$GOBPID %in%A$GOBPID return me false completely though I can manually see that there are common values in both. Why does this error occur? I would also like to mention the two files were read in using "read.delim"

Comment: I've added my code to reproduce the results. I (fairly) certain that my answer is correct - the issue is your data. What you need to do is construct a simple example and post another question. In this question, include your data using `dput` - for example `dput(B)`

Comment: @ csgillespie : Yes, the answer id definitely right but do not understand what the problem is with my data. Is it alright to post the same questiona gain ? Maybe I will add a link to the datasets.

Comment: @Paul Don't post the same question. The question is now I have two data frames (give them using `dput`). I try and use `%in%`, it doesn't do what I expect (give what you expect).